# Internal S3 generics with an lapply

Tags: r, oop, lapply

I have an S3 generic function that I would like to be an internal part of a package. I would prefer not to export it if possible. An interesting downside of this is that it seems that `lapply` is unable to find or use the proper S3 method. Does anyone know the reason behind this behavior? below is a reproducible example which involves installing a dummy package from my github.

In this case, the generic function is `docheck` which will return `TRUE` if the object is `"foo"` and `FALSE` otherwise.

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("jtlandis/SOExample")
#> Skipping install of 'SOExample' from a github remote, the SHA1 (27ab918c) has not changed since last install.
#>   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
library(SOExample)
```

The foo function is just an `NA` object with the `"foo"` class.

```r
foo
#> function () 
#> structure(NA, class = "foo")
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000015033878>
#> <environment: namespace:SOExample>
```

`fun_success()` just shows a case in which the internal (not exported) S3 function works.

```r
fun_success
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     docheck(x)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000013f83100>
#> <environment: namespace:SOExample>

fun_success(foo())
#> [1] TRUE
```

`fun_failure()` calls the same internal generic method, but fails

```r
fun_failure
#> function (x) 
#> {
#>     lapply(list(x), docheck)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000015e68df0>
#> <environment: namespace:SOExample>

fun_failure(foo())
#> Error in UseMethod("docheck"): no applicable method for 'docheck' applied to an object of class "foo"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R has been getting more picky about making sure S3 methods are properly registered. The normal method to register package generic methods is with the S3method() in the NAMESPACE file. But if you are trying to keep all of `docheck` unexported, then you'll need to register the S3 method yourself. You can do that with the `.S3method()` function. In your R file, add this line

```
# Existing line...
# docheck.foo <- function(x) T
# New line...
.S3method("docheck", "foo", docheck.foo)
```

This will allow the `lapply` to find the method.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and will apply it in my package since it fixes the issue. Still seems like a lot of extra work tbh. There isn't yet a good explanation to why `lapply` is unable to find the proper method. Maybe `lapply` evaluates in a new environment?