# purrr::map executes mapping function in different environments for named functions and formula functions

Tags: r, purrr, plumber, r-s3

I'm developing a `plumber` API and need to serialize a custom S3 class. As part of defining a custom serializer, I map over a list of instances of the S3 class. I have implemented a S3 method for `as.list` so that I can pass objects that `jsonlite::toJSON` can serialize.

When using `purrr::map` if I supply the bare function, the dispatch is unable to find the proper method. If I wrap it in a formula/purrr-style function, it works.

My question: **Why can't the bare function execution environment find the custom S3 method?**

This is a simplified version, but I have the routes saved into separate files which a main `plumber.R` file mounts.

```r
# plumber.R
library(plumber)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

myEnv <- new.env()

# custom S3 class
myEnv$myLilS3 <- function(x, y) structure(list(x = x, y = y), class = "my_lil_S3")

# S3 Method for my_lil_S3 class
myEnv$as.list.my_lil_S3 <- function(x, ...) unclass(x)

pr("myRoute.R", envir = myEnv)$run(port = 5555)
```

I'm using a local environment because in the actual use-case, there may be naming conflicts between sourced files.

To illustrate the discrepancy, I have three endpoints:

- `/function` use map with `as.list`
- `/formula` uses map `~as.list(.x)`
- `/single` uses `as.list` without map

```r
# myRoute.R
myPretties <- map2(1:5, 6:10, myLilS3)

#* @get /function
function(res) {
  res$setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  res$body <- list(values = map(myPretties, as.list)) |>
    toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)

  res
}

#* @get /formula
function(res) {
  res$setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  res$body <- list(values = map(myPretties, ~as.list(.x))) |>
    toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)

  res
}

#* @get /single
function(res) {
  res$setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")

  res$body <- list(value = as.list(myPretties[[2]])) |>
    toJSON(auto_unbox = TRUE)

  res
}
```

The `/formula` and `/single` endpoints work as expected, finding the custom S3 method in the `myEnv` which is used when creating the plumber router.

```
# GET /forumla
{
    "values": [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 2,
            "y": 7
        }, 
        ...
}

# GET /single
{
    "value": {
        "x": 2,
        "y": 7
    }
}
```

`/function` returns an error because mapping `as.list` uses the default function, leaving the values with a class of `my_lil_s3`, which `asJSON` does not know how to serialize.

```
# GET /function
{
    "error": "500 - Internal server error",
    "message": "Error: No method asJSON S3 class: my_lil_S3\n"
}
```

From the `as_mapper` [documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/as_mapper.html) I know it treats functions and formulas differently. Looking at the mapper functions I would still expect the `UseMethod` call to be able dispatch properly in both cases.

```r
as_mapper(as.list)
#> function (x, ...) 
#> UseMethod("as.list")
#> <bytecode: 0x000001c01ee2fba8>
#> <environment: namespace:base>

as_mapper(~as.list(.x))
#> <lambda>
#> function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
#> as.list(.x)
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "rlang_lambda_function" "function"
```

Comment: Hello Marcus, tested your example. It's weird that `map(myPretties, as.list)` does not work but `map(myPretties, \(.) as.list(.))` does. Also, lapply has the same behaviour.

Comment: Seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515108/internal-s3-generics-with-an-lapply

Comment: @Ric Villablba - Registering using `.S3method` per the linked question does also resolve the issue. Just like the original poster, I'm still curious as to why the behavior happened in the first place.

Comment: My theory: from `?UseMethod`  it follows that class methods are searched in the current environment  and in the registration database (in which `.S3method` registers the function). When you usse `~ as.list(.)`, a new function is created within the current env. as the parent env, in which `as.list.my_lil_S3` has visibility. But when you pass a function by name, say `as.list`, search occurs in the env of that function, because no new function is created, in case of as.list is the <namespace:base> env `environment(as.list)` . Thus, `UseMethod` cannot find the generic.

Comment: I was starting think something similar - ultimately `as.list` gets evaluated in the <namespace:base> environment where the generic is defined, where as with the formula gets evaluated in the environment where the lambda function is defined, inheriting from `myEnv`.  `purrr:::map` (and `lapply`) eventually call `as.list` through a C/C++ compiled code  which I'm guessing  affects the evaluation environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `purrr::map` and `lapply` end up calling compiled code. I didn't dig past that, but it seems that [@Ric Villalba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6912817/ric-villalba)'s comment explains the essence of why it happens. Inserting some trace code to print call stack tree

```
 # only trace on the first item (i.e. myPretties[[1]]$x == 1)
  trace(
    as.list, 
    quote(
      if(x$x == 1) walk(sys.parents(), ~print(sys.frame(.x)))
    )
  )
```

Bare function:
[image: Trace for the bare function]

Formula:
[image: Trace for the formula]

If I'm reading the trace correctly, the bare formula gets executed in the `<environment:base>` where as the formula version gets executed in environment in which the lambda function is defined (i.e. which has the S3 method defined).

Per the suggestion in the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68515108/internal-s3-generics-with-an-lapply), registering the method in the generic dispatch database allows for the bare function to be used with `purrr::map`.

```
.S3method("as.list", "my_lil_S3", "as.list.my_lil_S3")
```