# Internal Generic s3 function name starting with a "."

Tags: r

For a package all the internal functions start with a ".".
Example `.internalfunciton()` and `externalfunction()`. This is used for quick namespace exporting.

Now I am trying to write a internal s3 method. There seems to be problems with it working with the dot at the start of the function name.

Here is some examples I have come up with to test it:

```r
test <- function(x,...) UseMethod("test", x)

test.class <- function(x, ...) {
  print("works like a charm")
}


.dottest <- function(x,...) UseMethod(".dottest", x)

.dottest.class <- function(x, ...) {
  print("works like a charm even with a dot")
}
```

When I test it it ends up like this.

```r
item <- 5
class(item) <- "class"
class(item)
#> [1] "class"
BrailleR:::test(item)
#> Error in UseMethod("test", x): no applicable method for 'test' applied to an object of class "class"
BrailleR:::.dottest(item)
#> Error in UseMethod(".dottest", x): no applicable method for '.dottest' applied to an object of class "class"
```

This happens when I load the functions locally or use the load_all method afterplacing that test function code in the package or even after installing it as this particular version shows.

Edit: As pointed out in comments some of these tests were invalid anyways due to not being put in the NAMESPACE

It feels like I am missing something with s3 generics.

Below is some context and is the actual code

```r
.RewriteSVG =  function(x, file, type) {
  UseMethod(".ReWriteSVG", type)
}

.RewriteSVG.GeomLine <- function(x, file, type) {
  # Adding extra 1 as this gets us into the inner line.
  lineID <- paste(.GetGeomLine(type), "1", sep = ".")
  svgDoc <- XML::xmlParseDoc(file)
  nodes <- XML::getNodeSet(svgDoc,
                           paste0('//*[@id="', lineID , '"]'))
  
  # Split the line into smaller polylines
  line <- nodes[[1]]
  
  lineAttr <- XML::xmlAttrs(line)
  lineAttr <- lineAttr[!(names(lineAttr) %in% c("id", "points"))]
  lineAttr <- split(lineAttr, names(lineAttr))
  
  ## Get the line points
  attr <- XML::xmlGetAttr(line, 'points')
  coordinates <- strsplit(attr, " ")[[1]]
  
  ## As there will always be 100 points in a graph we can just easily split them into 5 groups
  nBreaks <- 6
  breaks <- seq(1, 100, length.out = nBreaks) |> round()
  start <- breaks[1:(nBreaks-1)]
  end <- breaks[2:nBreaks]
  1:(nBreaks-1) |>
    lapply(function(i) {
      segmentCoords <- coordinates[start[i]:end[i]]
      args <- lineAttr
      args$id <- paste(lineID, i, sep = ".")
      args$points <- paste(segmentCoords, collapse = " ")
      print(args)
      
      newPolyline <- XML::newXMLNode('polyline', parent=line, attrs = args)
      
      XML::addChildren(line, newPolyline)
    })
  
  # Remove old line
  XML::removeNodes(line)
  
  # Save modified svg doc
  XML::saveXML(svgDoc, file=file)
  
}
```

Errors message looks like this

> Error in UseMethod(".ReWriteSVG", type) :
> no applicable method for '.ReWriteSVG' applied to an object of class "c('GeomLine', 'GeomPath', 'Geom', 'ggproto', 'gg')"

Which comes from the

```r
lapply(x$layers, function(x, graphObject, file) {
    .RewriteSVG(graphObject, file, x$geom)
}, graphObject = x, file = file)
```

Comment: Which of these functions are you exporting in your namespace file? Are they configured to be S3 generics there as well? Are you using roxygen to build your package?

Comment: @MrFlick I am not exporting any of these functions in the NameSpace that now you mention it makes sense as to why the tests aren't working. However, these s3 methods are internal only and are called only from other internal functions. From my understanding this means it doesn't need to be in the Namespace.

Comment: Functions still need to be registered with the S3 mechanism. If you aren’t doing it with a namespace, you need to manually register. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68515108/2372064